# Background-image at a fixed position in outlook EMail

Tags: outlook, background-image, html-email

I am designing a HTML EMail which has a background image at a position. It works fine in GMail and Yahoo. But the image is not displayed in outlook. I am using VML also. But nothing helps.
Here is what I have tries so far.

This  has the image in its background:

```
<td class="content-wrapper" style="width: 100%;background: url(https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0135a40176b33deb024da1fea/images/5d40da6e-256c-4191-a9b8-d69ca8e49f46.png) repeat-y 97.5% 0;">
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" background-repeat:repeat-y; position: 97.5% 0;">
       <v:fill type="tile" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0135a40176b33deb024da1fea/images/5d40da6e-256c-4191-a9b8-d69ca8e49f46.png" color="#ffffff" />
        <![endif]-->       
                     <!--<div>-->
         ********************contents here**********************
      <!--</div>-->
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
        <![endif]-->
```

But nothing happened in outlook. Please suggest me with an best and optimized solution

Answer (score 0):

This is the Outlook fix that I use for Background images, set up for buttons with backgrounds. The image you're using needs to be hosted for this, and the URL has to go within the background attribute in the `<td>` and in `src=` in the VML. As this is a template I use, widths and heights need to go wherever mentioned and background colour can be applied in the HTML and the VML. (Then there is a table within the fix where you can put more HTML such as images etc.)

```
<!--Button-->
<td width="" height="" align="center" valign="top">
<table width="" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td background="http://dummyimage.gif" bgcolor="#c81400" width="" height="" align="center" valign="top">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:px;height:px;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="http://dummyimage.gif" color="#c81400" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
            <table width="" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<!--End button-->
```

Note: Keep in mind that this code won't work in Outlook if you have a background image within a background image (it'll work but will break everything), you need more complex VML for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply a width and height to the VML object:

```
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"
style="height:100px; width:100px;">
```

And the background repeat and position you have applied will not work. VML objects are not a background, they just mimic a background by creating an object and placing it underneath your content. Its is an effective but limited method.

If you need to move the object over, try slicing the background image with space on the side where you want it to move over.

It will repeat by default in outlook on the x and y axis and you can't control that.

You can supply a different image for the outlook background to what you will use everywhere else. Just use a different image path inside the VML object to what you use on the `background` attribute on the `td`.

Also note that outlook.com and AOL will need the background specified in a `background=""` attribute, and will not work if you specify it as a css background (`style="background:url();"`).

Hope this helps.